# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bitmap' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

i am currently trying to access data from contentful through graphQl in my gatsby app. however i come across below error,

> TypeError : cannot read bitmap of undefined.

PLEASE HELP. i have previously accessed my data from both of these components without hassle. the problem started when i was querying contentful

```
export const query = graphql`
   {
   img: file(relativePath: { eq: "pasta.jpg" }) {
     childImageSharp {
       fluid {
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG
     }
    }
   }

  menu: allContentfulMaloncuisine {
   edges {
    node {
    id
    title
     description {
       description
      }
      price
      category
      image {
       fixed(width: 50, height: 50) {
        ...GatsbyContentfulFixed_tracedSVG
        }
       }
     }
    }
   }
  }`

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <BackgroundSection
      img={data.img.childImageSharp.fluid}
      title="malons' Eat"
      styleClass="pasta"
    />
    <Info />
    <Menu items={data.menu} />
  </Layout>
)

const AboutPage = ({ data }) => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <BackgroundSection
      img={data.img.childImageSharp.fluid}
      title="about us"
      styleClass="cook"
    />
    <Info />
  </Layout>
)
```

Comment: Please add all the related code. Like where you are using this query.

Comment: i just did. thank you

Comment: Can you tell which part of the code is throwing the error? It must be mentioned in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

On your queries, remove `_tracedSVG` from the images

example: ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG
should be: ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid

This worked for me for a similar issue. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! i fixed it already. the issue cam from contentful. apparently the images i used was above 200kb so i deleted all of them and resized them. weird but proved effective.